# Creating dynamic or dependent list of choices in Survey123 Connect

Tags: arcgis-survey123-connect

I’d like to create a dynamic list (for lack of better term). Here’s an example:
I have two regions: 1 and 2.
I have 10 buildings: A, B, C etc.
Buildings A to E are part of Region 1. Buildings F to J are part of Region 2.
I have two drop-down lists: Regions and Buildings.

When users select Region 1, I’d like the “Buildings” drop-down to have only building A to E available to be selected. When users select Region 2, I’d like the “Buildings” drop-down to have only building F to J available to be selected.

That will help with the data validation and error catching process. I’m not sure if that functionality exists in Survey 123 Connect.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution from another blogger. See below link:
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-choice-filters/ba-p/894046